# MySQL 5.5 slow response time

Tags: mysql, database, joomla2.5

I've just installed MySQL 5.5 CE on a Windows Server 2008 R2 (SP1) with IIS 7.5.

Running a simple Joomla! 2.5.14 website, without extension, I've a response time of 2.8 seconds. Running a simple PHP file, the response time is in milliseconds, so I have excluded PHP/IIS problems.

Now, what I can do to optimize MySQL and reduce this response time?

I've already enabled "skip-name-resolve", set "key_buffer_size" as 512M and "query_cache_size" as 128M. My server has 2 CPU and 4GB of RAM.

Thanks!

Comment: Running "simple PHP" does not exclude Joomla problems... And you could try using WinCache with Joomla: http://blogs.iis.net/donraman/archive/2010/03/05/performance-improvement-in-joomla-using-wincache-user-cache.aspx

Comment: WinCache already enabled. ;)

Comment: If I were you, I'd sprinkle some time capturing functions throughout the scripts you're running and pinpoint which queries are being so costly.  (In this case, your joomla core files.  I'd be willing to bet there's a debug feature that does exactly this which you can simply enable.)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend enabling the [MySQL slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html) in order to confirm that the problem in fact lies with MySQL. Based on the results that appear (or don't appear) in the slow query log file, you can pinpoint the problem(s) and, if necessary, optimize your MySQL server configuration or SQL queries.